# Get cell value from object type cell in python openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have this code:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
    for cell in row:
          print cell
```

I want to print out the actual value of cell, in other words, what is actually the contents of that cell. I know this is easy, but I can't find it anywhere. I tried doing ws[cell], but it brought an error.

Here's what's given now:

```
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0296EFC0>
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0295F6F0>
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0295F6F0>
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0297E5D0>
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0297E5A0>
<openpyxl.cell.read_only.ReadOnlyCell object at 0x0295F6F0>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of a cell in `openpyxl` you need to use the `cell.value` method.

In your code:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A1:C2'):
    for cell in row:
          print cell.value
```

Comment: nice.. thanks. is there somewhere inthe documentation that shows all the methods for different objects? i couldnt find it, it just seems very broad level in there

Comment: I did not use the documentation to learn `openpyxl` I used this guide: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/. It has some really great information in it.